# Checking Shapefile type (Point, Line, Polygon) in ModelBuilder using python script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, python-script-tool, if-statement

I am creating a model and would like the input to branch off to different tools within the model based on the shapefile type (point, line, polygon). I haven't found a tool in ModelBuilder that will do this and am not very skilled in python.

Is there a tool I'm not seeing or a script that exists for this?

Comment: There is a code sample in the help that described how to do if/then branching in ModelBuilder using a Python Script tool.

Comment: Are you asking how to do the branching or how to do the identification of the geometry type?

Comment: I want the model to branch off to different tools based on the geometry type. So if a point file was ran through the model it would branch to a different process than if a polygon file was ran through the tool. Is this making any sense?